# How could I display these icons side by side and centered on the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the icons to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uusRe.png), and centered on the page.

HTML:

```
<aside class="social">
  <ul class="smicons">
    <li class="fbicon"><a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="img/fbicon.png"></a></li>
    <li class="twicon"><a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="img/twicon.png"></a></li>
    <li class="yticon"><a href="http://youtube.com"><img src="img/yticon.png"></a></li>
    <li class="igicon"><a href="http://instagram.com"><img src="img/igicon.png"></a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
.social {
  display: inline-block;
}

.smicons {
  background-color: transparent;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution based on your css .. check the css section and those comments. sorry for my bad english.

```css
.social {
 display:block;  /*need aside as a block element by default aside is  block */
  text-align:center;/*text align center set the ul section to center ;*/
}

.smicons {
  background-color: transparent;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: none;
   padding-left:0;/*ul element by default padding-left:40px;*/
  padding-top: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;/*inline-flex set those icon side by side */
}
```

```html
<aside class="social">
  <ul class="smicons">
    <li class="fbicon">
      <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-18/512/Facebook-3-128.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="twicon">
      <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/twitter-128.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="yticon">
      <a href="http://youtube.com"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-icons-color/512/youtube-128.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="igicon">
      <a href="http://instagram.com"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-icons-33/128/Instagram-128.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `flexbox` solution.

```css
.smicons,
.smicons li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.smicons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.smicons li {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="social">
  <ul class="smicons">
    <li class="fbicon"><a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25/FC0"></a></li>
    <li class="twicon"><a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25/FC0"></a></li>
    <li class="yticon"><a href="http://youtube.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25/FC0"></a></li>
    <li class="igicon"><a href="http://instagram.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25/FC0"></a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```